# Animate ng-repeat without ng-animate

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

Is there a way to animate the transition when the order of the model array bound to ng-repeat changes with pure css without ng-animate?

Comment: Actually I was looking yesterday for such implementation myself and haven't found one, so I would like to see something like that

Comment: You can of course, but implementing it not worth the effort. I would go with ngAnimate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  You just need to artifically change the CSS class assigned to the elements in the ng-repeat to trigger the animation.

For example in your ng-repeat dynamically assign the class from a scope variable and change the value in that variable when the ng-repeat is reordered:

```
<li class="animate_fadein_{{currentClass}}" data-ng-repeat="user in data_set | orderBy:dynamicOrder:order.reverse"><span>{{user.name}} {{$index}}</span></li>
```

Here's a fiddle I forked from an ng-repeat orderby example created by :
https://jsfiddle.net/meliax/dvgghvch/